# Send emails with Django and SMTP Google

Tags: django, smtp

I need to use google's SMTP mail server for my server to send e-mails to x recipients. But the mail never reaches the intended recipient. I have activated the non-secure applications in my gmail account and configured the following:

In Gmail I go to "Manage your GMAIL account" -> "Security" and activate 2-step verification. Then in "Manage your GMAIL account" -> "Security" -> "Application password" in selecting application I choose "Other (custom name)" and I add a name for the application and it generates a password of 16-digit characters.

Now the Django code is as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives


EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx' #contrasena de 16 digitos
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'default from email'

def send_user_mail(randomNumber):
    subject = 'Titulo del correo'

    message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, #Titulo
                                    "Su número es: "+str(randomNumber),
                                    'xxxxx@gmail.com', #Remitente
                                    to=['xxxx@gmail.com']) #Destinatario

    message.send()
```

in settings.py I added:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Am I forgetting something or doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mail will not be sent to anyone. It will print in console since you are using `console.EmailBackend`. Change it to `smtp.EmailBackend` or refer this  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/  and decide what to use. Also you need to switch on the Allow less secure apps option in your gmail.

Comment: Thanks. That help me